# How to refresh wx.StaticText that is out of class in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am having trouble in trying to get static text to refresh when the user clicks 'ok' on a different window.  I need the main window to refresh when the user adds something from a different window. Code:

```
import wx
import random
class oranges(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Testing Sample',size=(1024,768))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
        self.static_text=wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,str(random.randint(1,100)),pos=(500,500))
        re_button=wx.Button(self.frame,label='Refresh',pos=(200,200),size=(50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.refresh,re_button)
        re_buttoned=wx.Button(self.frame,label='ok',pos=(100,100),size=(50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.another_thing,re_buttoned)
    def refresh(self,event):
        self.static_text.Destroy()
        ra_again=random.randint(1,100)
        self.static_text=wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,str(ra_again),pos=(500,500))
    def another_thing(self,event):
        class apples(wx.Frame):
            def __init__(self,parent,id):
                wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Testing Different sample',size=(1024,768))
                self.frames=wx.Panel(self)
                self.static_text.Destroy()
                ra_again=random.randint(1,100)
                self.static_text=wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,str(ra_again),pos=(500,500))
        if __name__ =='__main__':
            apps = wx.PySimpleApp()
            windows = apples(parent=None,id=-1)
            windows.Show()
            apps.MainLoop()
if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    window = oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I get this error when I press the button: AttributeError: `'apples' object has no attribute 'static_text'`.  Sorry for the messy code as this is just to show what the problem is. Thanks a bunch in advance! Looking forward to the answers!

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
def another_thing(self,event):
    class apples(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self,parent,id):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Testing Different sample',size=(1024,768))
            self.frames=wx.Panel(self)
            window.static_text.Destroy()
            ra_again=random.randint(1,100)
```

since your not assigning window in that function python figures out that it is external to the local scope and looks up  global namespace matches (and maybe non-local/non-global namespaces?)

all that said I have a hard time comming up with a good use case for this ... you should probably try to avoid this type of code entirely rather than hack around it ...